# Issue with brackets ( using myblockquote)

Tags: brackets, csquotes

I have an issue with the code. When I try to put multiples ( in my case 2 ou 3 ) \myblockquote. There are 2 more brackets that appear and the quote doesn't always start a new paragraph.
The code I use is the following

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\SetBlockThreshold{2}
\newcommand\myblockquote[2]{%
  \blockquote{\hspace*{2em}\emph{\og #1 \fg}\hfill(#2)}\par}
```

Sometime it looks like this

`\myblockquote{on va arriver à ce qu’on appelle une Balance leadership. Un style de management équilibré avec des facteurs féminin et masculin. }{A}`

[image: Wrong one]

But other times , it looks like this

`\myblockquote{on va arriver à ce qu’on appelle une Balance leadership. Un style de management équilibré avec des facteurs féminin et masculin. }{A}

[image: Correct one]

Comment: Come on! 60 seconds and two downvotes? It must be a joke. Give OP at least a chance to explain the problem.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik at least the score is tie, I give him an upvote :).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: There seems to be a sequence of posts downvoted twice within a short period of time (from posting). This might be serial (down-)voting from users which will hopefully be reversed.